# Storing token id in iOS

Tags: ios, storage, token

In ios development I get the token id while app startup. I am using a MVC and I have to use this token-id at a couple of other controllers. Whats the best way to access the token id ?

Answer (score 0):

[Shared/ Singleton](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/) Class will serve your purpose.

[How to create singleton class in objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381085/how-to-create-singleton-class-in-objective-c)

[Singleton shared data source in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355449/singleton-shared-data-source-in-objective-c)